# How to use python to turn a .dbf into a shapefile

Tags: python, gis, arcmap

I have been scouring the internet trying to find a pythonic (sp?!) way to process this data..

Everyday we will recieve a load of data in .dbf format (hopefully) - we then need to save this data as a shapefile.

Does anyone have any links or any suggestions as to my process?

Comment: No idea if this is accurate, but: "Published maps do not contain actual geographical data. Instead, they link to data sets at a central remote location, which may be hosted by an ArcMap Server or available over the Internet." (http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/pmf) So it might not be the pmf file you actually need to update.

Comment: too true thomas! thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: i've edited my post with what is now my definate problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in model builder all along!

```
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: DBF2SHAPEFILE <XY_Table> <Y_Field> <X_Field> <Output_Feature_Class>
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting, datetime

# Adds the creation date to all of the previous shapefiles in that folder
filename = 'D:/test.txt'
fileinfo = os.stat(filename)
creation_date = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(fileinfo.st_ctime)
os.rename(filename, filename + '-' + creation_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")

# Script arguments...
XY_Table = sys.argv[1]

Y_Field = sys.argv[2]

X_Field = sys.argv[3]

Output_Feature_Class = sys.argv[4]

# Local variables...
Layer_Name_or_Table_View = ""

# Process: Make XY Event Layer...
gp.MakeXYEventLayer_management(XY_Table, X_Field, Y_Field, Layer_Name_or_Table_View, "")

# Process: Copy Features...
gp.CopyFeatures_management(Layer_Name_or_Table_View, Output_Feature_Class, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Answer (score 2):

To append the file's creation_date to its name, you need to obtain the creation date with [os.stat()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) and then rename the file with [os.rename()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename). You can format the date string with [date.strftime()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

```
import datetime, os

filename = 'original.ext'

fileinfo = os.stat(filename)
creation_date = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(fileinfo.st_ctime)

os.rename(filename, filename + '-' + creation_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
import os
import datetime
myfile = "test.txt"
creationdate = os.stat(myfile).st_ctime
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(creationdate)
datestr = datetime.datetime.strftime(timestamp, "%Y%m%d")
os.rename(myfile, os.path.splitext(myfile)[0] + datestr + os.path.splitext(myfile)[1])
```

renames `test.txt` to `test20110221.txt`.

Comment: I got this error message:Message File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> C:\Documents and Settings\DuffA\Bureaublad\Magneto\Rename+Date.py 18  
NameError: name '_' is not defined

Comment: `_` only works this way in the interactive shell (it contains the result of the previous expression). In a script, you need to assign variables yourself.

Comment: im really sorry but i don't understand what you mean! my programming knowledge is limited!

Comment: OK; I've changed the example to use variables. You'll still need to provide the names of the actual files to be renamed, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it without using ArcGIS, you could use [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs)'s python bindings or the [ogr2ogr utility](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) through a subprocess. You could use the utility through a windows batch file, which would be a lot faster than calling the arc process for every file if you have many to do...

As you know it's not a question of changing the extension, there is a specific format required.